# How to derive this factorization $ax^2 + bx + c = a(x − x_1)(x − x_2) $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quadratics, factoring

I faced this factorization formula $$ax^2 + bx + c = a(x − x_1)(x − x_2)$$ where $x_1$ is the first solution and $x_2$ is the second one. But I don't understand how the formula gets derived... Could anybody explain it to me? Thanks!

I know I can solve a quadratic equation and substitute the solutions into this formula $a(x − x_1)(x − x_2)$, but I want to understand how it works.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please take a moment to familiarize yourself with formatting mathematical notation, so that you may maximize the amount of attention to your questions.

Comment: @uniquesolution, Keatinge helped me with the formatting. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $$x_1+x_2 = -{b\over a} \implies b= -a(x_1+x_2)$$ and $$x_1x_2 = {c\over a} \implies c= ax_1x_2$$

so \begin{eqnarray} ax^2+bx+c &=& ax^2-a(x_1+x_2)x+ax_1x_2\\ &=& a(x^2-x_1x-x_2x+x_1x_2)\\ &=& a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I understand what's going on there!

Answer (score 5):

By the [**Factor theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem) for a polynomial of degree $n$ we have $$p_n(x_1)=0 \iff p_n(x)=(x-x_1)q_{n-1}(x)$$

therefore for $p_2(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, given the roots $x_1$ and $x_2$, we have

$$p_2(x)=ax^2+bx+c=a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$$

Answer (score 3):

You can also complete the square. Assuming $a \neq 0$ (necessary to be a quadratic):
\begin{align*}
ax^2 + bx + c &= a\left(x^2 + \frac{b}{a}x + \frac{c}{a}\right) \\
&= a\left(x^2 + \frac{b}{a}x + \frac{b^2}{4a^2} + \frac{c}{a} - \frac{b^2}{4a^2}\right) \\
&= a\left(\left(x + \frac{b}{2a}\right)^2 - \frac{b^2 - 4ac}{4a^2}\right).
\end{align*}
Then, using a difference of two squares factorisation,
$$ax^2 + bx + c = a\left(x + \frac{b}{2a} + \frac{\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}\right)\left(x + \frac{b}{2a} - \frac{\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}\right),$$
as requested.

Comment: I've never heard about this method "complete the square". I'm gonna read something about it. Thanks!

Comment: @VitaliiPaprotskyi Unless you've only heard of solving quadratics very, very recently, I'm pretty sure you'll know the method. It's "the" way of solving quadratics, and is the basis for the quadratic formula. Maybe you know of it by a different name?

Comment: @VitaliiPaprotskyi: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square.

Comment: @TheoBendit I know how to solve a quadratic equation using Vieta's formulas and using the discriminant. Does solving an equation by completing the square is the same as using the discriminant?

Comment: @TheoBendit I got it, I've seen that method before, just didn't know its name. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$a\neq 0$ so you can reduce to the case

$x^2+b’x+c’=0$ where $b’=\frac{b}{a}$ and $c’=\frac{c}{a}$

$x^2+b’x+c’=(x^2+2\frac{b’}{2}x+(\frac{b’}{2})^2)-((\frac{b’}{2})^2-c’)=$

$(x+\frac{b’}{2})^2-\frac{1}{4}(b’^2-4c’)=$

$
(x+\frac{b’}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{b’^2-4c’})(x+\frac{b’}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{b’^2-4c’})=0$

and so

$x_{1,2}=\frac{-b’ +/- \sqrt{b’^2-4c’}}{2}$

and

$x_{1,2}=\frac{-b +/- \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$

Now if you calculate $ a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$
with that solutions you get the initial equation

$ax^2+bx+c$

There is a more elegant method with which you can prove the equality, the  polinomial division.

Answer (score 1):

These are two common ways of describing a polynomial: a polynomial written the first way is relatively easy to compute the value of at a given $x$, the second makes it easy to find the roots, being $x_0$ and $x_1$.

They are, of course, otherwise equivalent, as can be seen by expanding the roots form and comparing the coefficients of the various powers of $x$: we get $a=a$, $b=a(x_0+x_1)$, and $c=ax_0x_1$.

The fact that polynomials can be factored in this way is called [The Fundamental Theorem Of Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra): a polynomial of degree $n$ (that is, its highest exponent with a non-zero coefficient is $n$) has exactly $n$ complex, possibly duplicate roots.  Unfortunately a full justification requires way more than just algebra to complete, but notice how:

1. Both $ax^2+bx+c$ and $a(x-x_0)(x-x_1)$ have, when expanded, $x^2$,$x$, and constant terms, and
2. Both have three free constants.

These suggest at least that they should be able to cover the same ground.

Comment: Great explanation! Thank you very much!